# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory while running python unit test

Tags: python, subprocess, python-unittest

I wrote following code in python unitest to get minikube ip.

```
def get_minikube_ip(self):
    process = subprocess.Popen(["minikube", "ip"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()
    if process.stdout is not None:
        minikube_ip = process.stdout.readline().strip()
        if not minikube_ip:
            raise Exception("Minikube is not running. Please, start minikube first.")
        return minikube_ip
    raise Exception("Minikube is not running. Please, start minikube first.")
```

But while running unitest i am getting error as  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I tried different solution by referring to similar questions asked by other people in stack overflow but not able to resolve it.

Comment: What's the output of running `which minikube` in your shell and running `print(os.environ["PATH"])` in the test code? For an executable to be found, it needs to be in a directory pointed in the PATH.

Comment: `process.stdout` will never be `None` here.

Comment: Hi Lie Ryan i tried what you suggested and got   KeyError: 'PATH'.

Comment: Hi Davis before going to process.stdout it is throwing me error.